# What's :eval (colon eval) in defcustom?

Tags: help, mode-line-format, manual

I am reading [this Elisp library](https://github.com/xuchunyang/github-notifier.el/blob/master/github-notifier.el#L61) and can't figure out what `:eval` is.

Comment: Instead of a link, this question would be better if you show the relevant code in the question itself.  And that would keep the question accurate even when the linked code is moved around (perhaps by lines added/removed prior to line 61).

Answer (score 8):

The doc string tells you this:

> "Mode line lighter for Github Notifier."

You couldn't otherwise know for sure what the code is about, or what `:eval` means in that context. That is, you couldn't know without checking where, and how, that user option (variable) is actually used in the surrounding code.

Normally, you could use `i` in the Elisp manual, and type `:eval`, to see where that's indexed in the manual. But there are no index terms that start with `:` (because of the tools that build the manual), and trying `i eval` doesn't really help.

However, you can search (`C-s`, repeating) the manual for `:eval`, and you will come to nodes in the manual having to do with the `mode-line` that tell you about this.

In particular, you'll come to node [Mode Line Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html), where you find this:

> `(:eval FORM)`
> A list whose first element is the symbol `:eval` says to evaluate
> `FORM`, and use the result as a string to display.  Make sure this
> evaluation cannot load any files, as doing so could cause infinite
> recursion.

Keep searching for `:eval` and you'll come to these nodes, which tell you more about the same use of `:eval`, that is, its use in a `mode-line` construct:

- [Properties in Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Properties-in-Mode.html)
- [Mode Line Top](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Top.html)

Another way to find this information would be to use `i mode line` in the manual. That takes you to node [Mode Line Format](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html), which has the other nodes mentioned as subnodes (in the menu you see there).

And after you try `i mode line`, and visit that node, a message in the echo area tells you that you're visiting the first of four matches for your input `mode line`, and that you can use `,` to visit the other matches, in turn.  Doing that takes you to the other nodes mentioned above.

All of this is without actually studying the code that uses the variable in question.  Of course, searching that Elisp file for the variable name will show you just how it's used, and there you'll see that it's used as a mode-line construct. That will show you the *particular* use, in context.

In sum:

- Emacs doc strings are a great entry point.
- `i` in the manuals is your friend.
- But index entries can't start with `:`, and index entries for just `eval` unfortunately don't really cover this.

  (Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, to add an index entry for `eval` that has to do with the `:eval` mode-line construct.)
- You can search throughout a manual using `C-s`.

---

(If you want to get to the web version of the manuals, you can use `G` (command `Info-goto-node-web`) when in the manual in Emacs, if you use library [Info+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPlus). That's how I quickly got the URLS for the above links.)

Comment: thanks for teaching me how to fishing, what's the command name for C-s  , i binds C-s to ivy swiper.

Comment: Use `emacs -Q` (no init file) to quickly find the default situation, including key bindings. `C-s` is bound to `isearch-forward`. And consulting the Emacs manual will also tell you about default bindings: `C-r i C-s RET`.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `defcustom`: if you look at the doc string of `defcustom` it says:

> (defcustom SYMBOL STANDARD DOC &rest ARGS)

In this case, the SYMBOL is `github-notifier-mode-line`, the DOC is "Mode line lighter for Github Notifier.", the ARGS are `:type 'sexp :risky t :group 'github-notifier)`. The whole quoted expression is the STANDARD value of this variable.

In fact, if you evaluate the `defcustom` in an emacs session, you can then ask about `github-notifier-mode-line` with `C-h v github-notifier-mode-line`: it will tell you its value and its value is exactly that quoted expression.

That's as far as `defcustom` goes. You have to dig a bit deeper to find out what exactly that value is doing. The hint is that the name of the variable indicates that it has something to do with the mode line. If you look further in the file you linked, that suspicion is confirmed: e.g. the first line of the file says:

> Displays your GitHub notifications unread count in mode-line

and the keywords line says:

> Keywords: github, mode-line

The clincher however is one of the last lines in the file that says:

```
(add-to-list 'global-mode-string 'github-notifier-mode-line t)
```

Now if you ask emacs about `global-mode-string` with `C-h v global-mode-string`, it tells you:

> String (or mode line construct) included (normally) in ‘mode-line-format’.

In other words, you got to look at the `mode-line-format` documentation to see what that `:eval` is doing. `C-h v mode-line-format` then tells you:

> A list of the form ‘(:eval FORM)’ is processed by evaluating FORM and
> using the result as a mode line construct.  Be careful--FORM should
> not load any files, because that can cause an infinite recursion.

IOW, whenever the mode line is updated, that code is evaluated and its value is plugged into the mode line as part of `global-mode-string`.

For more details on the mode line, consult the Emacs Lisp manual with `C-h i g (elisp) mode line format`. In particular, the subsection "Mode line variables" explains how `global-mode-string` is used.

Answer (score 3):

Run `C-h f defcustom RET` to show the help information for defcustom. This will tell you what arguments it expects. In particular, is says that this is the expected signature:

```
(defcustom SYMBOL STANDARD DOC &rest ARGS)
```

So this `:eval` thing is in the position of the argument called STANDARD. A few lines down it says:

```
SYMBOL is the variable name; it should not be quoted.
STANDARD is an expression specifying the variable's standard
value.
```

So this is just the value that this variable will have by default, unless the user customizes it. But it is a pretty funny–looking value! The hint is in the name of the variable: `github-notifier-mode-line`. This is a value that will be put into a mode line definition at some point, so we can look in the Elisp manual for information about that. Chapter [23.4.2 The Data Structure of the Mode Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html) has all the information about what can go into a mode line definition, including what `:eval` means.

Two other people just answered the question, so I’ll stop there and hope that between the three of us you get the information you need.